# Matching records against datetime intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

In SQL Server 2008 I have a table holding events and the datetime of the event. In a different table I have a list of possible time intervals as shown below. Does anyone have an example on how I can select from my events table only when the event datetime falls inside the intervals in my interval table?

```
FromDate                ToDate  
-----------------------------------------------           
2012-11-29 06:00:00.000 2012-11-29 07:00:00.000 
2012-11-29 07:00:00.000 2012-11-29 08:00:00.000 
2012-11-29 09:00:00.000 2012-11-29 10:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Events e
INNER JOIN Intervals i
ON e.EventDate BETWEEN i.FromDate AND i.ToDate
WHERE i.FromDate = '2012-11-29 06:00:00.000'
```

This is a base query that you can work from.  It selects a single interval, and makes sure the `EventDate` is between its date range.  With this, you can then modify the query to do things like aggregate data in each interval (`GROUP BY`'s for example) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
where whateverDate between FromDate and ToDate
```